# Alterantive to popup window alert in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have an alert that lets the user know that their selection has refreshed. What I would like to know is how can I display the selection change in a text label instead of a popup alert window to indicate the environment is loading and the environment is loaded. Thanks.

```
<section id="scripts">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Areas').change(function ()
    {
        ****Help-Environment is loading***
        Application.Refresh();
                    ****Help-Environment is loaded***
    });
</script>
</section>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here, and I'm certain I'm not alone. What do you mean by `text id="" format`? Are you wanting a custom kind of popup as opposed to a JavaScript `alert(..)`? Or are you wanting to toggle the display of a div to notify the user (no popup)? Should we know what `environment selection` means? If so, tell us. If not, it might make sense to remove it from your question to make your question more generic. Try clarifying your question a bit please.

Comment: Sorry about that. I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: much better! Give me just a sec to write up an answer

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is have an alert element on your page that defaults to `display: none;`, and then change it's content and display property on change.

**HTML**

```
<div id="alert" style="display: none;></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#Areas').change(function ()
{
    var alert = $('#alert');
    alert.html('Your Selection Changed!');
    alert.show();
});
```

This is about as basic an example as possible and should be very easy to extend with some CSS+jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use jqModal or similar.
https://github.com/eyoosuf/jqModal
It is designed for exactly this purpose.